# ASP.NET using images from 1 app in another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 1 ASP.NET app which is basically a image library (displaying, uploading, deleting and stuff).
And I have another ASP.NET app which needs to use this image library and images from it.

Is it possible to somehow forward an image from the library to the other app without downloading it. Also images in the library are kept in a database.

EDIT  (more specific):
The other app currently has a "input file" html which is supposed to upload an image. I want to replace that "input file" with the image library app. So i want to choose an image from the image library and then use it in the other app.

Comment: Since your "image library app" is web app and second app is web app as well - it is perfectly possibly; you can just use links like imageapp.com/image.png in your second app (so the client will be actually downloading the images, not the app).  As the question is written - it is to broad. Please narrow it down to specific points at which you're facing issues.

Comment: The images in the library are stored in a database in a binary representation, not kept as files on server, so imageapp.com/image links won't work, unless I send a whole binary representation which i think is not a good idea.
To try to narrow it down. The other app right now has an "input file" html that is uploading an image there and what i want to do with the image library is to replace that "input file" with the library and choose an image from there and not from my computer.

Comment: I think you should expose an API of your image library through an HTTP handler, so that you could use URL's like /yourImgLib/GetImage.ashx?id=123456. The code of your ashx class will just have to deal with getting the image binary from the database and stream it to the response using the appropriate content-type.

Comment: An idea: Have a temp folder in your app2. Display 50-100 images on a single page in app2. To display create thumbnails from the binary images in database and dump them in temp folder. app2 should point to images in temp folder. Since these are thumbnails they won't consume lot of disk space. You can manage disk space by deleting the oldest files regularly. Also you can check if image already exists to avoid recreating the thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks for ideas, i will try both and see what works best :)